# ANTLR4 Custom token types C#

Tags: antlr4

It's quite hard for me to explain using the title...
But essentially the situation is that I want to be able to create Classes or Types in my grammar.
I have my primitive types but other than that the only way I can think of making new "custom" types is if I allow a type to also be an IDENTIFIER, which causes issues on its own... Is there another way I am missing to look at this? And if not, how can I properly create it?

So far my type rules look something like:

```
var_type : type | VAR;
return_type : type | VOID;

type
    : primitive_type
    | IDENTIFIER
    ;

primitive_type
    : INT_TYPE
    | FLOAT_TYPE
    | BOOL_TYPE
    | STRING_TYPE
    | DYNAMIC
    ;
```

I am quite new to using Antlr...

**Edit**
The difference between *Var* and *Dynamic* is the same as C#(sorta, not really in the way that it's built, but the idea). *Var* just sets the type to the expression's type, while *Dynamic* actually DOES have a type, it just allows you to change(and keeps track of) the type in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Types that are defined in the source code of the language you are parsing would be a semantic concern.  That is, they are not a syntax concern (generally, the job of a parser is syntax validation).

If you introduce constraints on types being defined before their use, you could add a semantic predicate to check it at parse time (by collecting something like a hash map/dictionary of the types that you've seen so far.  Most "modern" languages would not accept that constraint.

That leaves semantic concerns to be dealt with after the parse has produced a parse tree.  ANTLR helps out by providing Visitors/Listeners to make it easy to process the parse tree for this type of thing, but it's still up to you to write code to handle this concern.

Generally, you'd write something that builds a symbol table (taking whatever scoping rules your language has into account), and then validate any type references against the symbol table for it's scope.  Of course, there are many ways to do this, as many languages handle it differently.

Comment: Of course, I did not mean to handle a type in the syntax. I just meant, the Visitor wouldn't be called if the correct syntax does not occur, so if I do not allow an IDENTIFIER there, the Visitor responsible for handling types is never called, thus no type would be created, forcing me to use an IDENTIFIER... I just asked if there's a better way...

Comment: yeah, you have to allow IDENTIFIER to be a valid alternative for your type rules.  That's pretty standard. You can always take a look at the antlr grammar repository to see how it's handled in other languages (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)